# Post a list to a controller with tag-helpers and dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I've seen similar questions regarding this issue, but the tag helpers is putting a spin on my question. What I want to happen is the user can choose from various seating levels, pick some seats from that level, and when they submit a bunch of objects with details regarding the number of seats picked at each level (along w/ some other details, omitted b/c I haven't got there yet) goes to the controller, which will then do some logic...

I have my model:

```cs
public class PerformanceDetailsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ZoneDescription { get; set; }
        public string ShowName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShowDateTime { get; set; }
        public string VenueName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfTickets { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> NumberSeatSelect { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "0" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "4" }
        };
    }
```

My view:

```cs
@model List<PerformanceDetailsViewModel>

<h1>@Model.Select(x => x.ShowName).First()</h1>
<h4>@Model.Select(x => x.ShowDateTime).First()</h4>
<h5>@Model.Select(x => x.VenueName).First()</h5>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        Choose Number of Tickets
    </div>
</div>
<form asp-controller="PerformanceDetails" asp-action="AddToCart" method="post">

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Model[i].ZoneDescription <br />
                @Model[i].Price.ToString("C")
            </div>

            <select asp-for="@Model[i].NumberOfTickets" asp-items="Model[i].NumberSeatSelect"></select>
        </div>
        <hr />
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

And my controller:

```cs
public void AddToCart(PerformanceDetailsViewModel numTickets)
        {
            var text = numTickets;
        }
```

The question is - what have I missed? The form renders fine, and has the data in it. I saw examples in various places that said to use a for loop rather than a foreach, so I'm doing that, but my model still comes across the wire empty, even though I checked in Chrome Dev tools and see that the form does have the data.

Also, I don't know whether to use a `List<>` for the controller method or not.

Another wrinkle is the `select asp-for` piece, because it expands out to a bunch of html, but I don't know how that affects the model, since each one gets a unique name that doesn't match the model name...

What am I doing wrong? And what do I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: you can't use the `asp-for="@Model[i].NumberOfTickets"` because the tag-helper will convert that into `[0].NumberOfTickets`, which is the name that the model binder is looking for, and that will never match. So you can't use the `asp-for` at all, you instead have to break it down to `id="@Model[i].NumberOfTickets" name="NumberOfTickets"`, which the model binder will like. And then your data will come through.

Also, must update the model in order to have the list of individual name items, so convert `public int NumberOfTickets { get; set; }` to `public List<int> NumberOfTickets { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

contoller:

```
public void AddToCart(PerformanceDetailsViewModel numTickets)
{
   ViewData["text"] = numTickets;

   return View();
}
```

And use ViewData at your view

Comment: Thanks for this, but the problem is that the numTickets variable isn't getting the data, and it should be...

Comment: I wish you success .